# Initializing a list of lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, collection-initializer

I'm designing a state machine class and want to use lambda expressions to represent conditions to satisfy the state transition objects. When I create a new State Transition object, I also want to pass it a list of Conditions that it can use to evaluate whether or not to move to the next state. However, I'm having problems initializing the list of Conditions. Here is a sample, simplified code example that illustrates the problem I'm having:

```
// Alias for delegate function
using Condition = Func<int, bool>;

class SomeStateClass
{
    public void SomeFuncToCreateConditionList()
    {
        List<Condition> conditions = new List<Condition>({
            { new Condition(x => x > 5) },
            { new Condition(x => x > 5 * x) }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm getting a syntax error for the curley brace on the line `List<Condition>({` saying `) expected`, and another syntax error on the closing parenthesis saying

```
new Condition(
; expected
} expected
```

I'm sure there is something stupid i'm missing here but I've been staring at it too long and can't seem to spot it. Any thought?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a mistake in your List-initializer.

It should be `new List<Condition> { ... }` instead of `new List<Condition>({...})`
You also don't need to wrap each `new Condition()` in  braces.

This should work:

```
// Alias for delegate function
using Condition = Func<int, bool>;

class SomeStateClass
{
    public void SomeFuncToCreateConditionList()
    {
        List<Condition> conditions = new List<Condition>
        {
            new Condition(x => x > 5),
            new Condition(x => x > 5 * x)
        };
    }
}
```

or, a shorter method:

```
public void SomeFuncToCreateConditionList()
{
    var conditions = new List<Condition>
    {
        x => x > 5,
        x => x > 5 * x
    };
}
```

Comment: ReSharper tells that `var conditions = new List<Condition> {x => x > 5, x => x > 5 * x};` would be the shortest form.

Comment: Or also `new List<Condition>() { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Works great and looks much simpler than my previous approach :-).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
new List<Condition> { ... }
```

or

```
new List<Condition>() { ... }
```

or if for some reason you want to use the syntax of the constructor

```
new List<Condition>(new[] { ... })
```